# What determines whether we go to Friendship Gulag?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've joined several games on the Roland rescue mission (["A Dam Fine Rescue"](http://www.ign.com/videos/2012/09/24/borderlands-2-walkthrough-a-dam-fine-rescue-full-main-missions-part-8)), and:

> some times Roland is rescued in Friendship Gulag instead of in Bloodshot Ramparts

What determines this outcome? Is it randomized for each game? Does it involve a plot decision I missed?

Comment: Don't know for sure, but we had a really tough time in the first fight and had done essentially no damage in about 5 minutes. I got the impression there was a time limit of 5-10 minutes for the Bloodshot Ramparts fight.

Comment: There was this dropship that arrived just as I destroyed the constructor. I assumed it was scripted. Perhaps it isn't.

Comment: @Ids apparently it's scripted to appear but only if you take too long (or just long enough apparently) to kill the warden. I'm surprised I didn't see it, I had a hell of a time with him solo in my second playthrough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Dam Fine Rescue has two outcomes, based on your performance during the W4R-D3N fight.

Destroy W4R-D3N before the barge that Roland mentions arrives and picks the W4R-D3N up?

> You will rescue Roland then and there and will not need to make a trip to the Friendship Gulag.

If you fail to do so, however...

> You will need to make a detour to the Friendship Gulag to rescue him.

Note that the first outcome merely circumvents the requirement of the second outcome - the story will play out the same way once the requirements of the second outcome have been resolved if you have to do so.

(Note: I have actually never failed to destroy the W4R-D3N, so I can't say if there's extra story bits to the second outcome inside the spoiler location.)

Comment: I've failed and succeeded to kill the W4R-D3N the first time, and there are no story differences. Roland says exactly the same thing both times.

Comment: @NathanSabruka Awesome. I just put the disclaimer there *just in case* there was special stuff that happened if you failed.